# Create a custom element in EditorJs

Tags: reactjs, editorjs

I added [EditorJs](https://github.com/Jungwoo-An/react-editor-js) plugin in my react js application:

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

import EditorJs from "react-editor-js";

import { EDITOR_JS_TOOLS } from "./constants";

class ReactEditor extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <EditorJs
        tools={EDITOR_JS_TOOLS}
        data={{
          blocks: [
            {
              type: "header",
              data: {
                text: "Editor.js",
                level: 2
              }
            },
            {
              type: "paragraph",
              data: {
              }
            },
            {
              type: "header",
              data: {
                text: "Key features",
                level: 3
              }
            },
            {
              type: "list",
              data: {
                style: "unordered",
                items: [
                  "It is a block-styled editor",
                  "It returns clean data output in JSON",
                  "Designed to be extendable and pluggable with a simple API"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              type: "header",
              data: {
                text: "What does it mean «block-styled editor»",
                level: 3
              }
            },
            {
              type: "paragraph",
              data: {
                text:
                  'Workspace in classic editors is made of a single contenteditable element, used to create different HTML markups. Editor.js <mark class="cdx-marker">workspace consists of separate Blocks: paragraphs, headings, images, lists, quotes, etc</mark>. Each of them is an independent contenteditable element (or more complex structure) provided by Plugin and united by Editor\'s Core.'
              }
            },
            {
              type: "paragraph",
              data: {
                text:
                  'There are dozens of <a href="https://github.com/editor-js">ready-to-use Blocks</a> and the <a href="https://editorjs.io/creating-a-block-tool">simple API</a> for creation any Block you need. For example, you can implement Blocks for Tweets, Instagram posts, surveys and polls, CTA-buttons and even games.'
              }
            },
            {
              type: "header",
              data: {
                text: "What does it mean clean data output",
                level: 3
              }
            },
            {
              type: "paragraph",
              data: {
                text:
                  "Classic WYSIWYG-editors produce raw HTML-markup with both content data and content appearance. On the contrary, Editor.js outputs JSON object with data of each Block. You can see an example below"
              }
            },
            {
              type: "paragraph",
              data: {
                text:
                  'Given data can be used as you want: render with HTML for <code class="inline-code">Web clients</code>, render natively for <code class="inline-code">mobile apps</code>, create markup for <code class="inline-code">Facebook Instant Articles</code> or <code class="inline-code">Google AMP</code>, generate an <code class="inline-code">audio version</code> and so on.'
              }
            },
            {
              type: "paragraph",
              data: {
                text:
                  "Clean data is useful to sanitize, validate and process on the backend."
              }
            },
            {
              type: "delimiter",
              data: {}
            },
            {
              type: "paragraph",
              data: {
                text:
                  "We have been working on this project more than three years. Several large media projects help us to test and debug the Editor, to make it's core more stable. At the same time we significantly improved the API. Now, it can be used to create any plugin for any task. Hope you enjoy. "
              }
            },
            {
              type: "image",
              data: {
                file: {
                  url:
                    "https://codex.so/upload/redactor_images/o_e48549d1855c7fc1807308dd14990126.jpg"
                },
                caption: "",
                withBorder: true,
                stretched: false,
                withBackground: false
              }
            }
          ],
          version: "2.12.4"
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ReactEditor />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

According to the documentation i can create a custom element:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <EditorJs holder="custom">
      <div id="custom" />
    </EditorJs>
  );
}
```

Question: I want to add as a custom element an `input`: `<input type="text"/>`, but i don't manage even if i do:

```html
<EditorJs holder="custom">
  <input id="custom" type="text"/>
</EditorJs>
```

Who knows how to add this custom element in the plugin above?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-editor-js-23opz

Answer (score 2):

I found in the documentation that i can create a plugin for editor.js:
https://editorjs.io/the-first-plugin. One of example looks like this:

```js
class SimpleImage {
  static get toolbox() {
    return {
      title: 'Image',
      icon: '<svg width="17" height="15" viewBox="0 0 336 276" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M291 150V79c0-19-15-34-34-34H79c-19 0-34 15-34 34v42l67-44 81 72 56-29 42 30zm0 52l-43-30-56 30-81-67-66 39v23c0 19 15 34 34 34h178c17 0 31-13 34-29zM79 0h178c44 0 79 35 79 79v118c0 44-35 79-79 79H79c-44 0-79-35-79-79V79C0 35 35 0 79 0z"/></svg>'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return document.createElement('input');
  }

  save(blockContent) {
    return {
      url: blockContent.value
    }
  }
}
```